# In W-OTS, could you XOR all public keys?

Tags: hash-signature

Since the signatures all generate the public keys, those can be derived from sig and proven by pre-commited XOR of every pub key compared with XOR of every signature end hash.

Comment: Are you asking if a hash function that XORs other hash functions retains cryptographic security?

Comment: yes sort of, does it? the question is asked in the context of Winternitz hash signature since I had the idea that it could shrink pub key size by 32x.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're proposing that we have a number of one-time-signatures (which, with the corresponding messages, hash to the corresponding public keys), and then we produce the xor of all the public keys.  Then, the receiver would validate all those signatures together (by computing the corresponding public keys, xor them together, and seeing if the result is the published xor).

If so, it doesn't work; an adversary could put together a forgery, that is, a series of messages and signatures that would evaluate to that same xor.  How he would do so is straight-forward; he would generate a series of messages and random signatures; he would then find the corresponding public keys.  Then, he would find a subset of those public keys that would xor to the published value - this can be done by solving a set of linear equations.  That subset would be the forgery.

Comment: W-OTS has a public key of 32*256 bit, quite large. I was thinking those could be reduced to just 256 bit, by XORing them together. At loss of security but it seemed to me it would still be like finding a needle in a haysack.

Comment: What are the linear equations?

Comment: If a hash function is secure, and it is computationally hard to find a pre-image for a specific output, is it not also hard to find 32 pre-images whose hashes combine, with XOR, to a specific output?

Comment: @phi: so, the attacker is bounded to using only 32 pre-images (rather than an arbitrary number); that's *not* quite as trivial, but still considerably simpler than finding a hash preimage.  Why don't you just hash the 32 public keys together?

Comment: an attacker still has to find pre-image to hashes, even if XOR combination of 32 hashes, sounds similar in hardness to if the 32 public keys were hashed, but hash would work as well as XOR.

Comment: the benefit is a public key size of only 32 byte instead of 1024 byte

Comment: has similar idea been used or proposed? learnt Lamport and W-OTS after you mentioned hash signatures

Comment: @phi: well, LMS uses a hash (with a prefix) to combine the various tops of the Winternitz chains to form a short public value.  XMSS uses a more complex LTREE construction to combine them, but does the same general idea; so, yes, the same idea has been proposed (and implemented) before...

Comment: I am looking at this in context of public ledgers: what if you only publish a proof that the signature was validated, consisting of the checksum signature, plus a XOR of all other signatures. those two 32 bytes then XOR together, and are hashed, generating the public key.

Comment: boils down to finding pre-image to one single hash

Comment: does not work..

Comment: what if the 512 bits in Lamport are represented by blockhashes, mapped to blocknumbers. the block height in Bitcoin and Ethereum is only a few million, but 256 ways to combine them is a very large number. the signature is then 256 block numbers, that when XOR with second half of signature, a XOR of all remaining bits, and hashed, equals public key

Comment: does not work either